# servlet program giving no out put

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I developed this code using eclipse kepler .I am not getting where is my error .I am not getting any output.Below is the my html page which is present inside webcontent folder of eclipse

### Home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>home html</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="myFirstServlet">
<input type="submit" value="invoke life cycle servlet" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

below is my servlet file in side src folder in side a package one

### LifeCycleServlet.java

```
package one;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

public class LifeCycleServlet implements Servlet {

    private ServletConfig config;

    public void init(ServletConfig sc)  {
        sc=config;
        System.out.println("in init");
    }

    public void destroy() {

        System.out.println("in destroy");
    }

    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "servelet life cycle info"; 
    }

    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter printWriter=response.getWriter();
        printWriter.print("life cycle service");
        System.out.println("service");
    }

}
```

below is my web.xml file which is inside WEB-INF

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>LCServelt</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>one.LifeCycleServelt</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>LCServelt</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/myFirstServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: make form `action=/myFirstServlet`

Comment: still it is not working

Comment: try override doPost() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without set methed="", the form send post request as default. And then the web.xml find which servlet to reply according to the mapping

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>LCServelt</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>one.LifeCycleServelt</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>LCServelt</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/myFirstServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then it call the doGet Method or doPost Method(depends on your request method).

```
public class LifeCycleServlet extends HttpServlet{

 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                 HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
   //Here call the service method.
 }
}
```

So, in this example, you'd better override the doPost method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the flush() method on the PrintWriter to commit the response.

Comment: Can you try setting the content type of the response? like in:
 response.setContentType("text/xml");

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>LCServelt</servlet-name>
<!-- modify LifeCycleServelt != LifeCycleServlet <servlet-class>one.LifeCycleServelt</servlet-class> -->
<servlet-class>one.LifeCycleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>LCServelt</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/myFirstServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: yes i modified but when i click the invoke life cycle servlet button nothing is happening.......